# Understanding some XML EBNF

Tags: xml, ebnf

I am reading the XML specification and I can't quite understand this rule:

```
CharData ::= [^<&]* - ([^<&]* ']]>' [^<&]*)
```

Here's what I think I understand:

`[^<&]*` - Any amount of optional characters that are not `<` or `&`

`-` Except if it matches

`([^<&]*` Anything that's not `<` or `&`

`']]>'` followed by `]]>`

`[^<&]*)` followed by anything that's not `<` or `&`

Answer (score 0):

I realized whilst writing the question that the answer was right in front of my nose all along. So I figured I'd still post it but with my realization to hopefully help someone out in the future.

`CharData` is a string.

It's a flamboyant way of saying a string can't contain `<` or `&`, nor is it to be considered a string if it's followed by `]]>`